# Are heated roads feasible?

Tags: internal-consistency

In the 22nd century fusion energy is as cheap as dirt.
A populist politician proposes building of heated roads that will automatically melt all snow and ice during winter.

What are the drawbacks of such roads? What will be the effect on nature?

Comment: Have you done any research on the topic before asking here? I have the impression this is a poorly researched technical question, with no relation to worldbuiling at all.

Comment: Research like this https://what-if.xkcd.com/130/

Comment: In the real world, cities such as Oslo and Helsinki have heated sidewalks so that they melt snow and ice in winter time, in order to prevent the pedestrians from slipping and falling over.

Comment: The premise is that energy is free, there is nothing expensive in placing conductors inside asphalt. It is a question about unintended consequences: maybe wild animals will occupy warm spots and jam the road.

Comment: I feel like this is a bit open-ended right now... "_what is the effect on nature_" is about as unbounded as you can get. Can you narrow things down a bit? Is there anything in particular you're interested in?

Comment: @Starfish Prime What happens if a 100 mi highway in Russia or Norway becomes heated?

Comment: Just need to maintain a temp above 0 deg c since the objective isn't for the welfare of animals, or paint snow leopards or bigfoots on road to scare any would be road kill candidates ;D

Comment: I have to agree, please narrow down the impact you wanted to resolve. “Impact on nature” is almost anything from giving news cancer which destroys unpollinated crops to global warming. One issue please. VTC for now.

Comment: @Andrey Godyaev  In the western mountains of the USA railroads sometimes built open sided roofed sheds over railroad tracks to deflect snow accumulation and snow avalanches from the tracks.  So possibly that might be an alternate proposal for keeping roads snow free in your world.

Comment: @M.A.Golding these politicians drive only by car of course :p railroads are not really an interesting subject to populize about.

Comment: "The premise is that energy is free" - _nothing_ is free. There is always a cost. Won't the planet heat up?

Comment: @Goodies  Sheds over railroads show that sheds over highways are possible.  What's sauce for the railway is sauce for the freeway.   One side might say you can build a shed over a road without tearing up the road and disrupting traffic, while another side might say that putting heaters in the roadbed will use a lot less material than building roofs over it.  Some people might say that some roads will need sheds, some will need heaters, some will need both, and roads in the tropics won't need either.

Comment: @M.A.Golding, yes, small roads.. a highway is 6x times the width of a railroad. This shed over long distances must be storm proof, etc.. For cars, I think heated roads are more practical. It's a waste, of course.. but there is plenty energy and it works. A wide shed covering a highway would be a huge investment! Material, maintenance.. And 6 to 10 months per year, you won't need, or like to see a shed over the road,  while the heater can be switched off. Use electricity for the heating.. you only need to put cables in the road. Oops am I a populist now?

Answer (score 3):

As @AlexP told, in Oslo and Helsinki city governments have installed electric elements in sidewalks to keep them ice- and snow-free. Similarly electric elements can be installed under the roads.

**Advantages**

- It is cheaper than clearing snow with shovels.
- There are less accidents and injuries by slipping.
- Using salt may have problems like seepage or cyanide in NaCl.

**Disadvantages**

A lot of energy is needed so the heating system should be used in a well calculated way.

Comment: Norway is a country of mountains that gets 95% of their energy from renewable hydro power. It makes sense there.